# Flutter :- Failed to build iOS app using flutter run iOS command . ** BUILD FAILED

Tags: flutter

I try to build iso app with flutter but i get always this error idk where did he come from any help pls ?
Error : https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmuHf.png

Comment: You can run this in your terminal "flutter build ios --verbose" and show the error code pls.

Comment: https://justpaste.it/4bufx

Answer (score 0):

Do you use two XCode on your computer ? I had that issue when i'm switching between XCode and Simulators.
For example if I build on XCode12 but against Simulator iOS15.2 it will definitively fail.

Try to quit clean up your project, restart the computer and try again it should do the work